# Uninitialized Value in String 'eq' Perl

Tags: string, perl, warnings, initialization

I'm getting a warning running one of my Perl scripts. The error is being thrown at a simple `if` statement where I'm testing if a string in an array is equal to another string.

My coworker and I have tried several scenarios and still haven't been able to resolve the warnings. I've tried to place all my research so far into this thread, so it is a little long, but please stick with it. I'm completely stuck and hoping one of the great minds of Stack Overflow can help me out!

The code generating the problems is:

```
if ($pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber")
```

The block of code around that section is:

```
my @pieces = split(/=/, $var);
if($pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber") {
     $promoNumber = $pieces[1];
} elsif ($pieces[0] eq "Type") {
# More similar code follows
```

My goal in the above code is to assign all the variables I've found in a text file to the respective Perl variables. I then insert those found variables into a SQL database.

The text file has several fields that can be in different orders, which is why I use the switch style if-elsif... to accomplish assigning values. There are also some fields I don't care about, such as Level, and I just ignore these fields. These fields however are the fields that cause warnings.

The `$var` is set to the following as it loops through...

```
PromotionNumber=000
RecordOffset=0
Code=0
SubCode=1
Level=0
```

When I hit "Level=0", I can pause in the PerlIDE.exe debugger and see that the string is split into Level and 0 and inserted in the array. However, as soon as the code advances to the `if` statement and tests `$pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber"` I get the warning.

I can even print out $pieces[0] right before the `if` statement, and it will print "Level".

If I change the code to the following the warning goes away...

```
my @pieces = split(/=/, $var);
if($pieces[0] eq "Level") {
    #My problematic variable test
}elsif($pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber") {
     $promoNumber = $pieces[1];
} elsif ($pieces[0] eq "Type") {
#More similar code follows
```

However, if I test for the "Level" string second, the warning comes back. The code below DOES have the warning.

```
my @pieces = split(/=/, $var);
if($pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber") {
    #My problematic variable test
}elsif($pieces[0] eq "Level") {
     $promoNumber = $pieces[1];
} elsif ($pieces[0] eq "Type") {
#More similar code follows
```

Why does Perl care which order I test in? Note, that I am testing SEVERAL other strings that are multiple elsif's down in my if-elsif statements that don't give this warning.

Any ideas? I really need to clear up this warning so that it doesn't flood the console when running. The script is working with the warnings though.

Exact error is:

> Use of uninitialized value in string eq at japdpmrijob.pl line 250.

Exact line of error (determined using Perl's debug utility in PerlIDE.exe) is:

```
if ($pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber") {
```

I can print out $pieces[0] and see the value. So I know it is defined with my value. I can also print out $pieces[1] and see my expected value. If I test for $pieces[0] eq "Level" first, the warning goes away and I can access both variables.

I am still confused...

It looks like the error is actually the "eq" being flagged as a variable. Any ideas on that?

Below you'll find a large chunk of the code. I included the entire `for` loop and several of the variables that I'm working with. Notice the `else` statement at the end of the if-elsif-else sequence, I added this to attempt stop the warning as noted by the third answer. This `else` statement prints my expected values every time the warning is called, so I know the values are present.

```
for my $cond (@conditions) {
    if($debug==1){print $cond."\n";}

    # Required database variables
    my $isRecord = 0;
    my $promoNumber;
    my $type;
    my $process;
    my $testValue;
    my $recordOffset;
    my $code;
    my $subcode;
    my $itemType;
    my $itemValue;

    # Function test variables
    my $itemTypeVar;
    my $newQualifier = 1;

    # Database Configuration
    my $dbApps = new Win32::ODBC("myDatabase") || die "Error: " . Win32::ODBC::Error();
    my @condVars = split(/\|/, $cond);
    for my $var (@condVars) {
        if($debug==1){print $var."\n";}
        my @pieces = split(/=/, $var);
        if( defined($pieces[0]) ){
            print "piece 0 defined!\n";
        } else {
            print "pieces 0 not defined!\n";
        }
        if( defined($pieces[1]) ){
            print "piece 1 defined!\n";
        } else {
            print "piece 1 not defined!\n";
        }
        if($pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber"){
            $promoNumber = $pieces[1];
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "Type"){
            $type = $pieces[1];
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "Process"){
            $process = $pieces[1];
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "TestValue"){
            $testValue = $pieces[1];
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "RecordOffset"){
            $recordOffset = $pieces[1];
            if ($recordOffset == 0) {
                $newQualifier = 1; }
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "Code"){
            $code = $pieces[1];
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "SubCode"){
            $subcode = $pieces[1];
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq "ItemType"){
            $itemType = $pieces[1];
            if($itemType eq "0") {
                $itemTypeVar = "ItemCode";
            } elsif($itemType eq "1") {
                $itemTypeVar = "ItemCode";
            } elsif($itemType eq "2") {
                $itemTypeVar = "Department";
            } elsif($itemType eq "5") {
                $itemTypeVar = "MixMatchCode";
            } elsif($itemType eq "12") {
                $itemTypeVar = "GroupCode";
            }
        } elsif ($pieces[0] eq $itemTypeVar){
            $itemValue = $pieces[1];
        } else {
            print "$pieces[0] and $pieces[1] not used.\n";
        }
        print "$var\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is the `$pieces[1]` expression, not `$pieces[0]`.  If you have a value of `$var` without a `=` (a blank line, for example) `split` will return a list of a single item.  Your tests for "Type" and "Level" only look at the first element and will work, but the block under "PromotionNumber" tries to look at the non-existent second element and generates the warning.

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting. It's not clear just which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to show us more of the code (at least the for loop that sets the value of `$var`). This is a very strange problem.

Comment: I am working to get the code over to my laptop, my test server is having issues with my thumb drive and being a test server we don't have it on a network. I'll update as soon as I get the USB drive working again.

Comment: @chepner the code has been added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for the error in the wrong place. For a warning triggered inside an `if-elsif-else` statement or other complex block of code, older versions of Perl may identify the warning as occuring on the first line of the statement.

```
------ warn.pl ------
my $x = 0;
my $y;
if ($x == 1) {         # line 3
} elsif ($x == 2) {
} elsif ($x == 3) {
} elsif ($y == 4) {    # line 7
}

$ perl5.14.2 -w warn.pl
Use of uninitialized value $y in numeric eq (==) at warn.pl line 7.

$ perl5.8.6 -w warn.pl
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at line 3.
```

Comment: We have an else at the bottom that should be a "catch-all". I should have the code posted momentarily. But, my coworkers and I have considered that the code could be elsewhere, but we are fairly positive it is in the "if-elsif" combination of tests.

Comment: Based on your input, it seems you encounter the "Level=0" line before you encounter an "ItemType" line. This means when you hit the final `elsif` clause, `$itemTypeVar` is not yet defined. And as @mob points out, this warning will probably be attributed to the initial clause of your big `if-elsif-else` statement.

Comment: @chepner THANK YOU SO MUCH! I went ahead and marked mob's answer as correct, but I probably would have been to stupid to figure out that it was a completely different variable causing my error. I don't know why I didn't think to test on that variable as well. By verifying that $itemTypeVar was defined before testing against it all the errors went away. Many thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

You might check to see if `$pieces[0]` is defined before you do comparisons. Most of the time this will prevent the warning:

```
my @pieces = split(/=/, $var);
my $label = defined($pieces[0]) ? $pieces[0] : ""; #if not defined init to ""
my $value = defined($pieces[1]) ? $pieces[1] : "";
if($label eq "PromotionNumber") {
     $promoNumber = $value;
} elsif ($label eq "Type") {
#More similar code follows
```

Comment: I tried adding `if ( defined($pieces[0]) ) { print "DEFINED!"; } else { print "NOT DEFINED!"; }` right before the problematic if statement. It prints out defined for every single test, including my problem tests, then still gives me a warning on the `if ( $pieces[0] eq "PromotionNumber" ) {` line of code. I'm completely stumped as to what Perl is complaining about!

Comment: Since Perl 5.10, the `//` operator replaces the `defined ... ? ... :` construction you have -- `my $label = $pieces[0] // ''`

Comment: @mob good to know. I'm stuck with using 5.8.6 so I'm a bit behind in those types of niceties.

Comment: @Kyle still the interpreter doesn't know it will be defined or not. You need to explicitly define the values you are using in comparisons.

Comment: I tried declaring @pieces to a 2 variable array manually, then assigning it the values from split. It still warns at that if statement. If you notice in the orig question, the crazy thing is if i test for "Level" first it goes away. If I test for it second, it warns...

Comment: @Kyle - Try use diagnostics; Maybe that will give you a more explicit error message. You could also try If(!defined($pieces[0]) || !defined($pieces[1]){next;}elsif($pieces[0] eq "yourValue"){...} that way you check both pieces to see if defined. When you say declare a 2 variable array you meant my ($piece1, $piece2) = split(/=/, @pieces) correct?